# How to remove rows in pandas python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I got this problem and have not idea how to do it with pandas, I know how to do it with openpyxl, but not with pandas. I provided a code below, I want to remove two rows and write something in a new cell.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2020], [1, 2, 3, 4]],
                                   names=['year', 'q'])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Items1', 'Items2', 'Items3'], ['new', 'old']],
                                     names=['Items', 'type'])

data = np.random.seed(123)
data = list(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), (4,6)))

Ldata = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
Ldata
```

Now it's like this

[image]

I want to remove second and third row, and to write a 'year' in first row first cell.

Like this

[image]

What is the best way to do this in pandas?

Comment: Those are not rows, are index names

Comment: After this I export it to excel, so I call them rows.

Comment: Albert Camus : « Mal nommer un objet, c'est ajouter au malheur de ce monde. »

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiindex columns. If you don't want to lose information but still merge the levels, the best option might be just to join different levels:

```
Ldata.columns = Ldata.columns.map('_'.join)
Ldata.reset_index(inplace=True)
Ldata

   year  q Items1_new Items1_old Items2_new Items2_old Items3_new Items3_old
0  2020  1          n          c          c          g          r          t
1  2020  2          k          z          w          b          a          r
2  2020  3          p          j          a          o          a          p
3  2020  4          z          t          o          e          a          q
```

Comment: This solution is very interesting, how can I add `index_col=[0]`?

Comment: What do you mean `index_col=[0]` ?

Comment: This is reseted indexes,  I want to be `year` column (index) to make an index.

Comment: Do you mean `Ldata.set_index('year', inplace=True)` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should get you close:

```
Ldata.droplevel(axis=1, level=1).droplevel(axis=0, level=1)
```

You have multi-indexes (on both column and row) that can be dropped.

Comment: It is very close what I need, when I add `Ldata.droplevel(axis=1, level=2)` I got `IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 2 levels, not 3`. Is there solution for this?

Comment: the column multi-index is has two levels, `items` and `types` with indices (0,1).  There is no third index to remove.